# How to model class with circular dependency c#

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm currently working on an application that generates mechanical gear profiles.
The issue I'm faced with is that gears need to be modelled not as individual entities but as elements in a gear train where certain aspects of an individual gear geometry is dependent on the mating gear(s).
Currently, I have class like this:

```
    {
        private double _moduleM; // normal module
        private double _teethZ; // teeth
        private double _profileShift; // profile shift for nonstandard centre distance
        private double _helixAngle; // helix angle of helical gears
        private InvoluteGear _matingGear;
        ...
        public methods etc..
    }
```

The difficulty is that the _profileShift (and a couple of other variables) are calculated by reference to the mating gear. I have a separate class for all the calculations.

One of the calculations is:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Standard Centre Distance is the normal distance between pinion and wheel centres when no profile adjustment has been made 
        /// </summary>
        public static double StandardCentreDistanceA(InvoluteGear g1) =>
            ((g1.TeethZ + g1.MatingGear.TeethZ) / (2 * Math.Cos(Radians(g1.HelixAngleBeta)))) * g1.ModeuleM;
```

Now the above works just fine but I really dislike the call to g1.MatingGear.TeethZ. It is awkward at best and I'm sure there must be a better way of modelling the class.

There are other calculations where things get quite complex and a feature of one gear changes the the formula to be calculated (such as when working with two mating external gears or one external and one internal gear).

I have tried introducing a 'GearPair' class but this only solves the problem when two gears are being considered and I'd really like a more general approach that can address the case of multiple meshed gears (such as found in a planetary gear set).

Comment: "I really dislike the call to g1.MatingGear.TeethZ" - Why? There is nothing inherently bad about referencing a sub-property. It might be problematic if such calculations could lead to infinite recursion, but I cannot tell from the example if that is the case. It might be useful to model the dependencies as a graph, that could allow for things like checks for circular dependencies, or to recalculate all dependent properties when one changes.

Comment: @JonasH Thanks for input. I'm inclined to agree g1.MatingGear.TeethZ is not so bad but there is a problem. I really want to consider gears as part of a train, Consider the case of 3 gears. The two outer gears have dependencies to the middle gear - OK. But the inner gear has dependencies to BOTH the mating gears. If I change the centre distance of gears 1 and 2, The profiles (_profileShift variable) of ALL the gears will need to change. I may try adding _priorGear and _nextGear variables and trigger a complete recalculation 1->2->3 if there is any change.

Comment: I would probably suggest moving the dependencies outside the gears themselves. If you have a 'train', put the gears in a list. Or a tree/graph structure for more complicated dependencies. You could also consider separating the properties that are fixed, from the properties that are calculated to make it clearer what is what.